# Layout of edge and node in graphviz

Tags: graphics, graphviz, dot, postscript

In graphviz I would like to have an edge that doesn't cross the node.
Here is my graph:

```
digraph G {
 rankdir=LR;
 fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans";
 fontsize = 8;

  node [
   fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"
   fontsize = 8
   shape = "record"
  ];

  edge [
    fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"
   fontsize = 8
 ];

  MethodContext [
    label = "{ <head> MethodContext | <parent> parent \l| nativeIP \l | ip \l| sp \l| receiver \l| method  \l|  flags \l| Temp Var 1 \l Temp Var 2 \l ... \l Temp Var n \l| Stack \l ... \l Stack \l }"
  ];

  MethodContext:parent -> MethodContext:head [tailport=e];
}
```

Without the tailport I got a nice vertical graph except that the edge is crossing the node. But as soon as I add `[tailport=e]` like in the example my graph is horizontal and the edge is still crossing the node.

How could I keep the node vertical and have the edge attached to the right side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who ever want to know the solution is

```
MethodContext:parent -> MethodContext:head:e;
```